# Как из ссылки спарсить необходимый тип?

Tags: java, url

В ссылке передается тип файла, который необходимо подставить к названию файла при загрузке. Он всегда идет после `file%2c`, как его оптимально вытянуть? Может есть пример с помощью JSOUP?

```
https://site.com/download?resid=7257139334599!7571&authkey=!AKRZu44V2I1I&ithint=file%2cpdf
```

или

```
https://site.com/download?resid=76CC13Arr773BD!3049&ithint=file%2cdocx&app=Word&authkey=!AKrtQi2maRE
```

как по мне не очень удачный вариант:

```
private String getTypeFile(String typeFile) {

    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(%2c)");
    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(typeFile);
    if (mt.find()) {
        return typeFile.substring(mt.start() + 3, mt.start() + 6);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если действительно `file.` всегда присутствует:
[String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
typeFile.split("file%2c")[1].split("&")[0];
```

Иначе, можно добавить:

```
if (!typeFile.contains("file%2c")) return null;
```

---

Более правильным конечно будет парсить URI как URI.
Пример *(опуская обработку ошибок)*:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters =
        UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(new URI(typeFile)).build().getQueryParams();
String fileName = parameters.get("ithint").get(0);
String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое тривиальное решение:

```
private String getFileExtension(String link) {
    int p1 = link.indexOf("file%2c");
    if (p1 == -1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect link!");
    }
    p1 += 7; // "file%2c".length() == 7
    int p2 = link.indexOf("&", p1);
    return p2 == -1 ? link.substring(p1) : link.substring(p1, p2);
}
```

Если разработка ведется с использование Android SDK, то можно воспользоваться методом [`getQueryParameter(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getQueryParameter(java.lang.String)) класса `android.net.Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = "https://site.com/download?resid=7257139334599!7571&authkey=!AKRZu44V2I1I&ithint=file%2cpd42rerfds=13=32&?f";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("file%2(.+)[a-z=?&.//_0-9]+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find())
    { System.out.print(str.substring(matcher.start()+6,matcher.end()) + " "); }
    System.out.println();
```

ищутся совпадения "file%2" и после подставляешь символы какие должны выводиться.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private String getFileType(String fileType) {

    final String FILE_TYPE_REGEX = "(%2c)(\\w{3})";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(FILE_TYPE_REGEX);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileType);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(2);
    } 
    return null;
}
```

**sout**: pdf / doc